# Hide navigation bars on Android when reopening app

Tags: android

I'm trying to hide the top and bottom navigation bars on Android devices when I run my app.  Right now, I have modified my "onWindowFocusChanged" and "onCreate" methods to have the following code fragment:

```
    final int screen = 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY | 
        View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(screen);
```

However, when I go back to the home screen on Android without closing the app, reopen my app, and then try to switch between pages on my app, the navigation bar briefly appears and then disappears between these switches.  I assume this is because the above methods are not being accessed.

How can I make sure that even when a user abruptly switches out of my app and then back into it, that the navigation bar will not briefly reappear when switching pages as a result?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Put them in onResume method. As onResume is called every time you come back to that activity

Comment: This seems to work - is there a way you can answer my question instead of commenting so others have a greater chance of seeing this solution if they have a similar problem?  Thank you!

Comment: No problem bro. Its great to hear that it worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the guide here: https://developer.android.com/training/system-ui/navigation

You need to add the code to three places:
onWindowFocusChanged, onCreate and onResume

Comment: Thank you!  Adding to onResume works - in addition, I tried a "goBack" button that essentially restarts the page and inserts the UiVisibility calls I had mentioned earlier :)